# Alert sequence when Push Notification comes in

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, push-notification

Please help me understanding this:

When home button is pressed and iPhone application goes in the background and a Push Notification is received. There is an alert being displayed which contains the message for that notification with "View" button on it. Where this alert is coming from -- IOS generating it?

In my code I wrote code for showing alert when notification comes in inside my

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)iApplication didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)iUserInfo {
```

method. And on this alert action I am showing my view controller. Now, I am ending up showing two alerts -- One which is coming from IOS (I believe) and on tap of view is taking me to last visited page of my app and Second which I created and on tap of View is taking me to desired page.

Please help understanding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you get two AlertViews instead of one if you click on `View`. Then you should check whether the application is active or not. Have a look at the **UIApplication Class Reference**
[UIApplication Class Reference #applicationState](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/applicationState)

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)iApplication didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)iUserInfo {
    if([application applicationState] == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        //show alert
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oliver Drobnik wrote a very detailed examination of the possible message flows when dealing with notifications and app state. The short version - if your apps not frontmost, the OS displays a notification and may launch your app in response to user actions; if your app is frontmost, you're responsible for everything, be it displaying an alert or some other processing.

http://www.drobnik.com/touch/2010/07/understanding-ios-4-backgrounding-and-delegate-messaging/